# iframe in chrome trouble

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

i have a basic page that was not in an iframe with a CSS sheet and looks fine. I put it in an iframe and the css is not getting applied (using chrome). Opening the same page on Opera, it works.. **The class is in all capitals.** Normally, this would not be an issue. but since the page has been in the iframe, the browser is skipping right over the class.

I can change the name of the class in the inspector(chrome), hit enter, then change it back and it will be applied. why?

Why is chrome doing this? What is the work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes do not support classes that have capital letters in them